# Sharing code parts (modules) with a team for a GWT/GAE Project

Tags: java, git, google-app-engine, gwt

For a distributed team (especially a temporary team), what is the best way to securely share code parts only while allowing each member (though not all code is shared), the member can still run the whole application.

By '*not all code is shared*' I mean, some parts (or modules) are compiled perhaps, so the member can run the whole GWT + GAE app while not getting all the source codes.

Is this something that is achievable?

Comment: Does the actual clientside GWT code need to be split and secured, or just the server?

Comment: Yes the client code also should be split

Comment: Depending on where the splits occur, it may be possible to adapt the ["Turducken"](http://www.slideshare.net/RobertKeane1/turducken-divide-and-conquer-large-gwt-apps-with-multiple-teams) approach with each team member only receiving compiled modules for code they do not have access to. All the modules would get loaded into the same page and communicate via an EventBus.

Comment: @Bjartr cool. Turducken approach looks like what I need. Do you happen to know real implementation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a private Maven Repository Manager, you could:

- Make API's (a collection of Java interfaces) available to all your devs
- Make dummy impls of those API's available to all your devs
- Make production impls available to a subset of your devs

Your devs will have to swap dummy/production dependencies using their local pom.xml files.

e.g. Steve can't have access to the production DB impl. Block his access to the prod DB impl jar from your private Maven Repository Manager. Steve will have to rely on the dummy impl that is publicly available.